# data-target with data-attribute instead of id

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Instead of feeding a data-toggle attribute with an id attribute, ie data-target="#this_item" I'd like to feed it a data attribute instead.  Will something like data-target='[data-eventid="@eve.EventId"]' function with bootstrap?

```
@foreach(var eve in Model.Events)
        {
            <div class="card-header event" id="this_item">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#this_item" aria-controls="this_item"></button>
            </div>
        }
```

Preferable alternative:

```
@foreach(var eve in Model.Events)
        {
            <div class="card-header event" data-eventid="@eve.EventId">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target='[data-eventid="@eve.EventId"]' aria-controls="[data-eventid="@eve.EventId"]"></button>
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@foreach(var eve in Model.Events)
        {
            <div class="card-header event" data-eventid="@eve.EventId">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="[data-eventid='@eve.EventId']" aria-controls="[data-eventid='@eve.EventId']"></button>
            </div>
        }
```